# Pretty urls using nginx and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to introduce pretty urls on an existing WP site:

```
/foo
```

should be interpreted as

```
/index.php?page_id=5&param=foo
```

I tried, in my server block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # other fastcgi stuff ...
}
location / {
    rewrite /foo /index.php?page_id=5&param=foo last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

But wordpress is redirecting (301) to:

```
/foo-another-post-title-with-same-prefix
```

Where I'm wrong and how to debug?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically permalinks are obtained with

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

While for troubleshooting you can [enable rewrite_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log):

```
rewrite_log on; # http block
```

And [set loglevel](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#error_log) to `notice`

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location /foo {
      rewrite ^ /index.php?page_id=5&param=foo last;
}
```

should do the job :)